# Reverse Lipschitz condition and continuity implies bijection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous function with $\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid\geqq c\mid x-y\mid$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, where $c>0$ does not depend on $x$ and $y$. Then $f(\mathbb{R}=R$.

I could show that $f$ is 1-1 and $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a closed set. I try to get a contradiction by assuming $p\in\mathbb{R}\setminus f(\mathbb{R})$ and using the fact that $p$ cannot be a limit point. However, I could not reach anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The fact that it’s an injection and has a reverse lipschitz condition means that the inverse function $f^{-1}: f(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. But then $f(\mathbb R)$ is open as the pullback of an open set. If $f(\mathbb R)$ is both open and closed, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\neq y$ then $\vert x-y \vert >0 \implies \vert f(x)-f(y) \vert >0 \implies f(x)\neq f(y) $. So $f$ is inyective.

Write $Y=f(\mathbb{R})$, so $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow Y$ is biyective and exists $g=f^{-1} : Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $y_1 = f(x_1),y_2=f(x_2) \in Y$, we have :

$$ \vert f(x_1)-f(x_2) \vert \geq c \vert x_1 - x_2 \vert $$
$$ \implies \vert y_1 - y_2 \vert \geq c \vert f^{-1}(y_1)-f^{-1}(y_2) \vert $$
$$ \implies \vert g(y_1)-g(y_2) \vert \leq \frac{1}{c} \vert y_1 - y_2 \vert $$

So $g$ is continuous  $\implies f(\mathbb{R})$ is open and closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and $f(\mathbb{R}) \neq \emptyset$ we have that $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$.